# ESQL for splitting a string into mulitple values

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Following Input xml field needs to be substringed for 6 characters and each 6 characters should be splitted and saved in the option field of output.

```
Input: 
<feature>124414500045563879</feature>

output:
<option>124414</option>
<option>500045</option>
<option>563879</option>
```

Is there any tokenizer function available in IIB ESQL to achieve the above result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, no there isn't a String Tokenizer function in ESQL.

But you could use the following procedure as base to achieve your goal. This method splits S on Delim into an array in Env (Environment.Split.Array[]) 
and removes Environment.Split before refilling it.

In your case, you don't need the Delim, you should work with a fixed length in the Substring part.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Split (IN S CHARACTER, IN Env REFERENCE, IN Delim CHARACTER) 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE P INTEGER; 
   DECLARE Idx INTEGER 1; 

   SET Env.Split = NULL; 

   REPEAT 
      SET P = POSITION(Delim IN S); 
      IF P = 0 THEN 
         SET Env.Split.Array[Idx] = S; 
      ELSE 
         SET Env.Split.Array[Idx] = LEFT(S, P - 1); 
         SET S = SUBSTRING(S FROM P + LENGTH(Delim)); 
         SET Idx = Idx + 1; 
      END IF; 
  UNTIL P = 0    
  END REPEAT;    
END;
```

Source: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=97845&

Comment: Thank you vincent. I will try the above approach.

Comment: I followed the above approach and nailed the output.

Comment: @ranaa Glad to read that! (: If it worked well, you can set this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to take the value of feature as bitstream, build a new BLOB message from it, and have it re-parsed using a message definition that describes the tokens in that value. After the re-parsing, you can further process the new logical message.

Comment: Really good answer. I generally use a loop for a small number of elements say less than 20, see above, due to the performance cost of setting up and invoking a Parser but where there could be lots and lots of elements creating a MessageModel for the DFDL parser could significantly reduce overhead. Remembering that every line of ESQL is a call to the underlying interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in split function in ESQL. However one can make his own split function in ESQL. You can use following procedure for spliting a string on the basis of delemeter and store it in array.

```
CREATE FUNCTION split(string CHARACTER, delimiter CHARACTER, IN result REFERENCE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE index INTEGER 1;
    WHILE SUBSTRING(string BEFORE delimiter) <> '' DO
        EVAL('SET result.index[' || CAST(index AS CHARACTER) || ']=''' || SUBSTRING(string BEFORE delimiter) || '''');
        SET index = index + 1;
        SET string = SUBSTRING(string AFTER delimiter);
    END WHILE;
    EVAL('SET result.index[' || CAST(index AS CHARACTER) || ']=''' || string || '''');
END;
```